# Puppet Recursive File Permissions

Tags: permissions, puppet

When using a Puppet file resource with recurse=>true is it possible to have directories and files get different permissions?

That is we generally want to remove read/execute permissions from group for all non-directory files. However, directories should retain the execute permission since that is required to enter the directory.

Some utilities (e.g. umask) are intelligent enough to deal with this but it looks like Puppet may not be. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4):

In fact puppet does this by default:

> "When specifying numeric permissions for directories, Puppet sets the search permission wherever the read permission is set."

see also:
https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/file.html#file-attribute-mode

A more explicit alternative is to use symbolic modes like "ug+X", this will only affect directories and will even allow to make directories searchable/executable without them being readable (which does allow you to enter the directory but then not read its contents... not sure if that is what you want though).

Answer (score 0):

> When using a Puppet file resource with recurse=>true is it possible to have directories and files get different permissions?

No, but I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60858936/1667352) that would help you if you need to deal with anything besides the 'x' bit.  Basically, the defined type takes an 'fmode' and 'dmode' argument for defining different modes per type and applies those recursively and quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet adds directory read permission automatically.

For example, if you set mode => '0640' recursively on a directory then puppet will set mode '0640' for all files under that directory and directories themselves will be set to '0750' mode.

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/types/file.html#mode

Alternatively a puppet module like recursive_file_permissions can be used.
https://forge.puppet.com/modules/npwalker/recursive_file_permissions